# React-moralis, function useMoralisQuery, searching item by currentPatientWalletId address

Tags: reactjs, moralis

I'm trying to query patient's consultation data via currentPatientWalletId which is a variable am passing to the useMoralisQuery hook,butit cant.bt once i hard code the currentPatientWalletId it works.please help.

```
import React,{useEffect,useState} from 'react';
import { useMoralis, useMoralisQuery } from 'react-moralis';
function PatientConsultationReport({currentPatientWalletId}) {
    const { isAuthenticated,Moralis,user,isWeb3Enabled,authenticate,enableWeb3 } = useMoralis();
    const { fetch,data,isLoading,error } = useMoralisQuery(
        "consultation",(query) => query.equalTo(
        "patientWalletId",currentPatientWalletId),[],{live:true} );     
return (
    <div>
        <div>PatientConsultationReport</div> <hr />        
         {
                    error ? (<span></span>):
                    isLoading ? ( <span></span>):
                      
                      (<pre>{JSON.stringify(data, null, 2)}</pre>)
                }
    </div>
  )
}

export default PatientConsultationReport
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code seams to be syntax correct. Console log the currentPatientId wallet and check its case. Moralis database usually stores the ethAddress in lowercase, so that might be the problem.
Check out this article. https://forum.moralis.io/t/the-future-of-the-javascript-sdk/14501

Comment: thanks so much...it worked. The case of the values in currentPatientId was the issue. The article was also helpful